# Wordpress doesn't execute jquery code correctly

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have worked with the google map api and a carousel system to have a nice list of locations.

Locally the script works perfect and without any issues.

I'm currently using: https://github.com/haripaddu/jQuery-Vertical-Carousel

At first when integrating the code the functions wouldn't work and I saw on other posts the solution was to wrap it hence it's what I did but the script still doesn't work.

**What doesn't work is the fact that even if I have 10 `li` the carousel doesn't start it just displays all my `li`.**

**Edit:** From what iv'e tested what I think is happening is that the jQuery wrap doesn't allow the `$.fn` to work properly as it is never the `$(".recentArticles")` that is returned but always the full DOM element.

I have tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ /*my code*/ });
```

Also:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ /*my code*/ });
```

I also had to wrap the line:

```
 var currentItemOffset = $("> :nth-child(" + currentItem + ")", carouselGroup).offset();
```

Like this:

```
var currentItemOffset = jQuery(function($) {$("> :nth-child(" + currentItem + ")", carouselGroup).offset();});
```

Otherwise I would get an error.

In my functions.php I also made sure to include jQuery when enqueuing my javascript:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'verticalCarousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jQuery.verticalCarousel.js', array( 'jquery' ), '5.0.9', false );
```

However even with all this is still doesn't work no animation, it displays all the events even if I have 4.

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebarLocation">
    <div class="recentArticles">
        <div class="recentArticlesHeader">
            <a href="#" class="ca_goUp"><i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
        </div>
            <ul id="sidebarLocation" class="recentArticlesGroup vc_list sidebarLocationUl" style="">
                <li id="0"><a href="javascript:zoomIn(0,6,'Header 1')" class="card"><img src="lopburi.jpg"><div class="cardContent"><h4>Header 1</h4><p></p><p>address</p>
<p></p><p></p><p>+603 3333 3333</p>
<p></p></div></a></li>
                <li id="1"><a href="javascript:zoomIn(1,6,'Header 2')" class="card"><img src="bangi.jpg"><div class="cardContent"><h4>Header 2</h4><p></p><p>address</p>
<p></p><p></p><p>+603 3333 3333</p>
<p></p></div></a></li>
                <li id="2"><a href="javascript:zoomIn(2,6,'Header 3')" class="card"><img src="portklang.jpg"><div class="cardContent"><h4>Header 3</h4><p></p><p>address</p>
<p></p><p></p><p>+603 3333 3333</p>
<p></p></div></a></li>
                <li id="3"><a href="javascript:zoomIn(3,6,'Header 4')" class="card"><img src="factory.jpg"><div class="cardContent"><h4>Header 4</h4><p></p><p>address</p>
<p></p><p></p><p>+603 3333 3333</p>
<p></p></div></a></li>
            </ul>
        <div class="recentArticlesFooter">
            <a href="#" class="ca_goDown"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.fn.verticalCarousel = function(myoptions) {
        var carouselContainerClass = "vc_container";
        var carouselGroupClass = "vc_list";
        var carouselGoUpClass = "ca_goUp";
        var carouselGoDownClass = "ca_goDown";

        var options = myoptions;
        var carouselContainer;
        var carouselGroup;
        var carouselUp;
        var carouselDown;
        var totalItems;

        var setContainerHeight = (function(){
            var containerHeight = 0;
            var marginTop = 0;
            if (options.showItems == 1){
                containerHeight = $("> :nth-child(" + currentItem + ")", carouselGroup).outerHeight(true);
            }
            else{
                for (i = 1; i <= options.showItems; i++) {
                    containerHeight = containerHeight + $("> :nth-child(" + i + ")", carouselGroup).outerHeight(true);
                }
            }
            var nextItem = options.showItems + currentItem;
            marginTop = $("> :nth-child(" + nextItem + ")", carouselGroup).css("marginTop");
            containerHeight = containerHeight - parseInt(marginTop);
            $(carouselContainer).css("height", containerHeight);
        });
        var setOffset = (function(){
            var currentItemOffset = jQuery(function($) {$("> :nth-child(" + currentItem + ")", carouselGroup).offset();});
            console.log(currentItemOffset);
            var carouselGroupOffset = $(carouselGroup).offset();
            var offsetDiff = carouselGroupOffset.top - currentItemOffset.top;
            $(carouselGroup).css({
                "-ms-transform": "translateY(" + offsetDiff + "px)",
                "-webkit-transform": "translateY(" + offsetDiff + "px)",
                "transform": "translateY(" + offsetDiff + "px)"
            })
        });

        var updateNavigation = (function(direction){
            console.log(currentItem);
            if (currentItem == 1){
                $(carouselUp).addClass("isDisabled");
            }
            else if (currentItem > 1){
                $(carouselUp).removeClass("isDisabled");
            }
            if(currentItem == totalItems || currentItem + options.showItems > totalItems){
                $(carouselDown).addClass("isDisabled");
            }
            else if (currentItem < totalItems){
                $(carouselDown).removeClass("isDisabled");
            }
        });

        var moveCarousel = (function(direction){
            if (direction == "up"){
                currentItem = currentItem - 1;
            }
            if (direction == "down"){
                currentItem = currentItem + 1;
            }
            updateNavigation();
            setContainerHeight();
            setOffset();
        });

        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).find("." + carouselGroupClass).wrap('<div class="' + carouselContainerClass + '"></div>');
            carouselContainer = $(this).find("." + carouselContainerClass);
            carouselGroup = $(this).find("." + carouselGroupClass);
            carouselUp = $(this).find("." + carouselGoUpClass);
            carouselDown = $(this).find("." + carouselGoDownClass);
            totalItems = $(carouselGroup).children().length;
            updateNavigation()
            setContainerHeight();
            setOffset();
            $(carouselUp).on("click", function(e){
                if (currentItem > 1){
                    moveCarousel("up");
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            $(carouselDown).on("click", function(e){
                if (currentItem + options.showItems <= totalItems){
                    moveCarousel("down");
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    };
});
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(".recentArticles").verticalCarousel({
             currentItem: 1,
             showItems: 2,
        });
 });
```

Comment: just to remind you didn't forgot to add css file. Right?

Comment: You should narrow the problem down. 0) Do you have errors in your console? 1) Is jquery loaded? If so, is it loaded in the head or body? 2) Read about javascript closures

Comment: @ShravanShrama css is fine what doesnt work is I say `showItems: 2,` but it only outputs all the data and doesn't start making the carousel

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden jquery is loaded by default in wordpress in header. the probelem is even if I have 10 `li` it shows them all instead of creating the carousel

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: @Kyon147 no zero errors with the code posted here

Comment: Have you tried replicating it within a JSfiddle?

Comment: From what I understand from my testing wordpress doesn't like the $.fn because when I check my code at no poin in the offsets it actually returns $(".recentArticles") but returns the html element $ instead.